# Best Practice for Updating a Many-to-Many Join Table?

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

This is a question about how best to assign or update multiple entries in a Many-to-Many Join table.  In simpler terms, the ability to amend the category or tags for an article or blog.

In this application I am building I have a Category table (category) and Article table (called musings).

Because each Article can belong to many Categories (and each Category can be assigned to many Articles), I have a Join Table for this relationship (category_musings).  I have set up constraints - so that deleting an Article, deletes all its associated entries in the Join Table.  But deleting a Category is forbidden if it is currently assigned to an Article.

### WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:

I want the end user to be able to update/amend/remove multiple categories for a given article (musing).

### MY WORK SO FAR:

I have figured out a way to display the current category values in a multiple style dropdown using the following functions

First I get a list of all categories

```
//Return list of categories
public function categories($column)
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
$query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

return $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, $column);;
}
```

Then the categories currently assigned to a specific musing

```
//Return categories selection for each musing
public function getMusingCategoryList($id)
{
$sql = "SELECT category AS categories
              FROM musings 
              JOIN category_musings ON musings.musing_id=category_musings.musing_id
              JOIN category ON category_musings.category_id=category.category_id
              WHERE category_musings.musing_id=:musing_id";
$query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

$values = [
':musing_id' => $id,
];
$query->execute($values);

return $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0);
}
```

Both return arrays which I then pass to a another function to create my dropdown.  This is the PHP code in the front-end

```
$data = new \norm_musing\MusingData();
$Musing = $data->getMusing($_GET['id']);

$name = 'multi_dropdown';
$options = $data->categories("1");
$selected = $data->getMusingCategoryList($_GET['id']);

$result = $data->multi_dropdown( $name, $options, $selected );
```

And this is the dropdown creation function, which I later pass to a form, together with all the other relevant field data for the musing

```
//Create dropdown for categories
public function multi_dropdown( $name, array $options, array $selected=null, $size=4 )
{
    /*** begin the select ***/
    $dropdown = '<select class="form-control" name="'.$name.'[]" id="'.$name.'" size="'.$size.'" multiple>'."\n";

    /*** loop over the options ***/
    foreach( $options as $key=>$option )
    {
            /*** assign a selected value ***/
            $select = in_array( $option, $selected ) ? ' selected' : null;

            /*** add each option to the dropdown ***/
            $dropdown .= '<option value="'.$key.'"'.$select.'>'.$option.'</option>'."\n";
    }

    /*** close the select ***/
    $dropdown .= '</select>'."\n";

    /*** and return the completed dropdown ***/
    return $dropdown;}
```

This produces a String with the necessary Form HTML code to create the dropdown list, with the current values (verbose) selected. And all the user has to be capable of is holding down CTRL and clicking with a mouse at the same time, if they want to make changes.

But now I must figure out a way to update the Join table, if the user changes the selections (or ignore if they do not).

The dropdown box returns as an array

```
$selection = $_POST['multi_dropdown'].
```

e.g. there are 6 categories - choose 1 and 4 in the list - the array value is [0, 3]

For the purposes of verbosity, so I can understand what is going on, I create this php code to handle my form response

```
if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) 
{
$aCategories = $_POST['multi_dropdown'];
if(!isset($aCategories)) 
{
echo("<p>You didn't select any categories!</p>\n");
}
else
{
$nCategories = count($aCategories);
$categoryID = $data->categories("0");

echo("<p>You selected $nCategories categories: ");
for($i=0; $i < $nCategories; $i++)
{
  echo($aCategories[$i] . " ");
  echo($options[$aCategories[$i]] . " ");
  echo("(id: " . $categoryID[$aCategories[$i]] . ") | ");
}
echo("</p>");
$nCount = $_POST['count'];
$newSelected = $data->getMusingCategoryList($_POST['id']);
echo("<p>Originally you had $nCount categories: ");
for($i=0; $i < $nCount; $i++)
{
  echo($newSelected[$i] . " ");
}
echo("</p>");

exit;}}
```

Which produces output like this (id being the primary key from the category table)

```
    You selected 2 categories: 0 Aging (id: 3) | 2 Health (id: 4) |

    Originally you had 1 categories: Happiness
```

### MY QUESTION:

Should I simply DELETE all entries in the Join Table that match the Musing ID - followed by INSERT of the new selections??  It would be potentially wasteful where no changes were made, so first I'd presumably need to do some sort of array comparison.

What would be BEST PRACTICE here?

Is there a much simpler way to allows users to ADD and UPDATE multiple categories or tags for an article (like a blog entry or in this case a musing)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best practice approach to this problem would be to leverage MySQL's "INSERT IGNORE INTO" or perhaps "REPLACE INTO" (but I think this does 2 queries under the hood).

See http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html for reference.

Comment: Aha - that sounds like the sort of thing I need - thank you.  My current solution was to delete all the matching entries and rebuild with new inserts  - but that is creating a lot of unnecessary primary IDs in the Join table.

Comment: I was wondering though - what if I originally had two or more entries for the same article in the join table - and then reduced it to one.  REPLACE INTO would overwrite the first - but presumably would ignore or overwrite with the same value the others.  Then I'd have to delete duplicates wouldn't I, or at least ignore them in any future query?

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution - I'm not quite seeing how REPLACE INTO or INSERT IGNORE INTO could achieve the same thing

```
//Delete all categories for a given musing ID
public function deleteMusingCats( $id ) {

   $sql="DELETE FROM category_musings WHERE musing_id = :musing_id";
   $query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
   $values = ['musing_id' => $id];
   $query->execute($values);

   }


//Insert new category for musing
public function updateMusingCats( $a, array $b, $n ) {  

$stmt = $this->connection->prepare("
                 INSERT INTO category_musings (category_id, musing_id) 
                 VALUES (:catID, :musID);
                                  ");  

for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) 
{
  $stmt->bindValue(':catID', $b[$i], \PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue(':musID', $a, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
}

return $i;
}
```

which I only call if there are changes between the array sent to the form and the array received back from the form.

```
if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) 
{
    // Simple number array of the list items selected
    $aCategories = $_POST['multi_dropdown']; 

    if(!isset($aCategories))   {
        // No categories selected. Abort!
        header("Location: /norms_musings");
    } else {
        $nCategories = count($aCategories); // Number of categories selected
        $categoryID = $data->categories("0");  // Create complete category ID array

        for($i=0; $i < $nCategories; $i++) 
        /* Create array of selected categories the number value from the
        dropdown list corresponding to the place in the full category list array */
            $a[]=$options[$aCategories[$i]]; 
            $b[]=$categoryID[$aCategories[$i]]; // Create array of selected category IDs
        }

        $nCount = $_POST['count'];
        $newSelected = $data->getMusingCategoryList($_POST['id']);

        $equal = ($a==$newSelected);

        if ($equal) {
            // No Changes Made!
            header("Location: /norms_musings");
            exit;
        } else {
            $data->deleteMusingCats($_POST['id']);
            $arrayDiff = (array_diff($a,$newSelected));
        }

        if ($data->updateMusingCats($_POST['id'],$b,$nCategories)) {
            header("Location: /norms_musings");
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "An error occurred";
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```